# Possible to implement "guiders" in HTML & CSS?

Tags: javascript, css, html

I want to implement a "guider", a dialog box that guides a user through an application, by visually introducing the user to important features: http://jeffpickhardt.com/guiders/

I want features such as: attach the guider to an element on the web page, moving the guider inside the browser window and outside, I want clicks inside the guider to change the webpage (while the guider remains intact), I want to add animations to the guider...

In the above hyperlink the guider is implemented in JS. Is it possible to implement this (while creating modular code) in a widely supported technology like HTML5/CSS?

I'm afraid jS won't be supported as widely... And are my concerns real? Should I really preoccupy about not using jS?

Comment: You will need to use a technology which can handle events if you want some of this functionality, realistically JS is a sensible option. These days it is very widely supported, I wouldn't worry too much about lack of support, perhaps offer cutdown functionality for those with JS disabled.

Comment: @dougajmcdonald: Can't HTML5/CSS3 handle events?

Comment: I would say JavaScript is more widely supported that HTML5

Comment: @JohnAssymptoth I believe so, however I would still pick JS as a sensible option due to it's maturity compared to some of the newer HTML5/CSS3 technologies and support on older browsers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can safely assume that javascript will be supported on practically all browsers which have support for HTML5 and CSS (particularly CSS3) - this is definitely the case for all of the major browsers including mobile OS browsers for iPhone, Android, and WP7.

Doing this with pure CSS may be possible but with something like jQuery it's a breeze.

It was reasonably common a decade ago for users to disable javascript but not so much these days.

Comment: Agree. Using html5+css3 is way more risky. 1 in 50.000 will disable js, while 10.000 will have an old IE

Comment: Good point - but it's be worth pointing out that you can get HTML5 backwards compatibility with JS tools such as Modernizr (which instructs the browser to treat HTML5 elements as DIV elements in the DOM).